# oracle support of pro *c++

Tags: oracle10g

Recently I installed oracle 10g and previously I was working with 9i.I noticed many changes and most intriguing was the pro *c++ was not there.I googled the reason but was not able to find satisfactory results.Why has oracle discontinued its support?Anyone know the exact reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pro*C/C++ seems to be alive and well even in 11g; [Oracle Database Application Development](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/application_development/index.html). Though it is a feature of the Oracle client install which I believe is on Disk 2/Companion CD if you have the media, or you can download just the client installer from [Oracle Database Software Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/database/index.html).